# GraphQL response error message from DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, graphql, serialization

I can make CRUD in GraphQL using Django as a backend. My `Mutation` is meta class is based on `DRF` serializer.

I had search with term `DRF, GraphQL, serializer, ... etc`. Most of the will be topic related to make the endpoint, but it does not go to detail of `response` the error message. And most of the time I found DRF without GraphQL answer

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = (
            'id',
            'question_text',
        )

class QuestionSerializerMutation(SerializerMutation):

    class Meta:
        serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
        model_operation = ['crated', 'update']
        lookup_field = 'id'


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    xxx = QuestionSerializerMutation.Field()
```

Body

```
mutation{
  xxx(input: {questionText: "a;lsfjkdsajfdsjf;sjfsajdfkd;lsafjl;asfdsjf;lajflsadjf;alsjf;lasfsj"}){
    id
    questionText
  }
}
```

**Expected result:**

GraphQL return the error message from `Serializer` because my payload is exceed 50 characters

**As is:**

No error message raises

```
{
  "data": {
    "xxx": {
      "id": null,
      "questionText": null
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:**
How response with `serializer.error` in GraphQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should query for `errors` that have `field` and `messages`

```
mutation{
 xxx(input: {questionText: "a;lsfjkdsajfdsjf;sjfsajdfkd;lsafjl;asfdsjf;lajflsadjf;alsjf;lasfsj"}){
   id
   questionText
   errors {
      field
      messages
  }
 }
```

I actually wrote a CRUD django-graphene rest serializers library here, can check out the examples as well: https://github.com/topletal/django-model-mutations, I believe the original serializers mutations work similar